# Trying to setup a dropdown menu correctly

Tags: html, css, navigation, dropdown

I am trying to setup a drop down navigation menu.  My goal is to position the navigation list in the center of the screen with the the background extending across the entire width of the page.

My problem is that when I hover over a certain tab,  it causes the entire menu to position itself down, instead of just the dropdown list appearing under neath the tab I am hovering over.

```
<div class="navigation">
        <ul class="nav-list">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Shop</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">New</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Used</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Refurbished</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Deals</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Today</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Monthly</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Seasonal</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Sell</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">New</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Used</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Refurbished</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Help</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">FAQ's</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Settings</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Cart</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Orders</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Account</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

.navigation {
    background-color: #262626;
    display: block;
    opacity: 0.9;
    text-align: center;
}

.navigation ul {
    display: block;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
}

.navigation ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-top: 8px;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
    text-align: center;
}

.navigation ul li a {
    color: white;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 500;
    padding-top: 8px;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
    padding-left: 18px;
    padding-right: 18px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.navigation ul li a:hover {
    color: #b3b3b3;
}

.navigation ul li ul {
    display: none;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.navigation ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}

.navigation ul li:hover ul li {
    display: block; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Brentonr, do add `position:absolute` in your css class `.navigation ul li ul`

Comment: Thanks. That fixed the main problem, what about aligning the drop down to be underneath each tab.

Comment: Drop down is already aligned underneath each tab. Just do change- add background-color:grey in class .navigation ul li ul and add one more class ".navigation ul li ul li a" and add "color:black" in it so you can view menu listed.